# vector of class without default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Consider the following class:

```
Class A
{
    public:
       A() = delete;
       A(const int &x)
       :x(x)
       {}
    private:
       int x;
};
```

How can one create an `std::vector<A>` and give an argument to the constructor `A::A(const int&)`?

Comment: Is it asking too much to try to actually compile your code before posting away? `Class`, `std::vector<A(3)> ...` and `std::vector v(100);` are all nonsense.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> How can I create a `std::vector` of type `A` and give an argument to `A`'s constructor?

```
std::vector<A> v1(10, 42);  // 10 elements each with value 42
std::vector<A> v2{1,2,3,4}; // 4 elements with different values
```

> How would I add 3 to the vector?

```
v.emplace_back(3);          // works with any suitable constructor
v.push_back(3);             // requires a non-explicit constructor
```

The lack of a default constructor only means you can't do operations that need one, like

```
vector<A> v(10);
v.resize(20);
```

both of which insert default-constructed elements into the vector.

Comment: To add to this answer (and please correct me if I'm wrong): in order for the first constructor to compile, there has to exist an implicit conversion from `int` to `A`, and an assignment operator. If either of these is absent (which is not the case in the question), it won't work. 

<offtopic> This made me think: why doesn't there exist a variadic constructor to initialize object with multiple parameters? </offtopic>

Comment: @JorenHeit: Almost. It does need an implicit conversion constructor; without that, you'd have to say `A(42)` or `{42}`, not just `42`. It also needs a copy or move constructor (not assignment operator), but that's a general requirement for `vector`.

Answer (score 7):

Templates are not instantiated in one go : they only instantiate what is needed. `A` satisfies all the conditions for the following (constructing an empty vector) to be valid :

```
std::vector<A> v;
```

However, as `A` does not have a default constructor, the following (creating a vector with default-initialized content) would fail :

```
std::vector<A> v(100);
```

And that's a good thing. However, valid methods will be instantiated fine :

```
v.emplace_back(42);
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is in how you add elements into the vector and what member functions of the vector you use.

```
std::vector<A> v;
v.emplace_back(3);
```